# What is that in Ruby, Python Perl that they get executed on command line and can be used in system admin work while PHP and Java etc can not be used?

Tags: language-agnostic, system

Why can't we make a language say for eg Java also to be working like them? Is it purely a design decision or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nothing.**

Every system that can run Java at all, and that can run Ruby, Perl, or Python programs from the command line can also run Java programs from the command line.  I do it every day on Windows and Linux, for example.

Comment: But we can't use Java for System Admin work so it means these languages (Ruby, Python, Perl) are more intimately connected with the system.

Comment: @user1590011 Sure you can.  For example, you can use [Rundeck](http://rundeck.org/) to deploy code to a server - a classic sysadmin task.  Rundeck is written in Java.

Comment: Yes that confirms my doubt. What is possible in one language should be possible in another.Thanks alot

Comment: PHP can be run from the command line too.  you just, uh, should probably use something else for a command-line app.